# NoMethodError in Chefs#show ... undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm following the Getting Started With Rails Guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles
and am having trouble getting show.html.erb to work.

I've diverged from the tutorial only to the extent that the tutorial uses:

`rails generate model Article title:string text:text`

but I've used

`rails generate model Chef name:string email:string`

The problem is that my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @chef.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @chef.email %>
</p>
```

brings up a "NoMethodError in Chefs#show"..."undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".

What am I doing wrong please?

Here's my ChefsController:

```
class ChefsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    @chef = Chef.new(chef_params)

    @chef.save
    redirect_to @chef
end

private
  def chef_params
    params.require(:chef).permit(:name, :email)
  end

def show
    @chef = Chef.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

Comment: Can you post the show method of your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the **`show`** method above the **`private`**

```
class ChefsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    @chef = Chef.new(chef_params)

    @chef.save
    redirect_to @chef
end

def show
    @chef = Chef.find(params[:id])
end

private
  def chef_params
    params.require(:chef).permit(:name, :email)
  end

end
```

Any `method` that is defined under the `private` is treated as `private method`